# GM 4L60-E Rebuild Questions - Part 1

Tags: automatic-transmission, gm, 4l60e, rebuild

I am in the process of rebuilding my first 4L60-E  (I've done a 4L30-E  before) and I had a couple questions.

1st: In terms of the input drum pistons I know there are both aluminum and steel models, and that the new steel models need new return springs to work due to centrifugal forces bending the springs. I do not have the return springs needed for the new overrun clutch piston but I already bought new bonded pistons for each of these. Is there any chance I could interchange these? Meaning could I use new steel bonded 3/4 and forward pistons but use the old aluminium overrun piston, or do I have to use all of the same kind?

2nd: My current understanding is that the pressure manifold switch is used to essentially tell the computer what position the manual valve is in. Save for a lengthy explanation, lets just say I do not need this functionality in terms of electronics. Would it be problematic if I were to not reinstall the pressure manifold switch? Could I simply block off the holes where the fluid would go if it were there or is this something that would cause internal problems in the transmission.

There may be more questions in the future but thanks for the help!

Comment: While this has nothing to do with the validity or clarity of your question, your first sentence about "*my first 4L60-E*" and then saying (in the same sentence behind parens, "*I've done a 4L60-E before*" is a little confusion. Can you clarify what you have and haven't done? PS: Great overall question! I wish I had more tranny experience to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Also, are you planning on running a manual valve body? If that's the idea, I don't think you'd need the pressure manifold ... but don't take my word on it.

Comment: That's a typo, I apologize I meant to say I've rebuild a 4l30e. In terms of the manifold switch I'm probably going to plug up the holes and not install the switch I don't think that'll cause any issues. If anybody disagrees please let me know. Also does anyone know about the first question I asked regarding the pistons?

Comment: Not a clue ... give it a little bit of a chance though. We don't get these kinds of questions, so those with the mad skills may not have seen it yet. Also, don't take my *opinion* on the pressure manifold as gospel. It's a gut check with the caveat I had listed. I'm a GM guy through and through, but have not done much with rebuilding trannies. I'm surprised you're rebuilding the 4L60e, just because they have the week sunshell, unless you got a monster-in-a-box, or something. I'm looking forward to getting the 4L60e rebuilt in my Silvy. I feel it doing some strange shifting, lol.